# Laravel BadMethodCallException: Method [signdoc] does not exist

Tags: ajax, laravel, post, controller

Sorry for the long post. I am new to Laravel. I am trying to add an online hand signature functionality to a controller. I have chosen to use the javascript library https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad. I want to use an ajax call to the controller to save the signature image through php but i get a http 500 error whenever I try make the ajax call. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm all out of ideas.

In my laravel log

```
[2018-12-27 22:18:12] local.ERROR: BadMethodCallException: Method [signdoc] does not exist. in D:\...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php:82
```

On the view, I am able populate a signature pad with the button functionalities. This is the javascript from the view where the ajax called is made. I followed this guide https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad/issues/167

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("test");
    var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(document.getElementById('signature-pad'), {
        backgroundColor: '#c6c6c6',
        penColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
    });

    var signButton = document.getElementById('sign');
    var cancelButton = document.getElementById('clear');
    var undoButton = document.getElementById('undo');
    signButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if(!signaturePad.isEmpty()){
            //TODO
            //save picture
            var data = signaturePad.toDataURL('image/png');
            var imagen = data.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
            var fdata = new FormData();
            fdata.append('imgData', imagen);
            console.log(data);
            console.log(window.document.location);
            var url =
            jQuery.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                type:"POST",
                dataType: "json", //datatype expected to be returned
                url:"/transaction/modify/signdoc",
                data: fdata,
                sucess: function (data) {

                    if(data && data.status == "success"){

                        bootbox.alert("signed document!!" + data.info);
                    }
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            }).done(function(msg) {
                // Image saved successfuly.
                alert('success');
            }).fail(function (data) {
                alert('failed');
            });
        }
    });

    cancelButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        signaturePad.clear();
    });

    undoButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        var data = signaturePad.toData();
        if (data) {
            data.pop(); // remove the last dot or line
            signaturePad.fromData(data);
        }
    });

</script>
```

In my route

```
Route::get('report/transactionsreporting','TransactionsController@reportindex');
Route::get('report/AverageNightlyRate','TransactionsController@reportindex');
Route::get('report/transactionsProportionRate','TransactionsController@reportproportionrate');
Route::get('report/transactionsAverageRental','TransactionsController@reportaveragerental');
Route::get('report/transactionsGroupSize','TransactionsController@reportgroupsize');
Route::get('report/transactionsInquiryCheckInDate','TransactionsController@reportinquirycheckindate');
Route::get('report/transactionsClosed','TransactionsController@reporttranclosed');
Route::get('report/transactionsRate','TransactionsController@reportindex');
Route::get('report/inquiryCheckInDate','InquirysController@reportinquirycheckindate');


Route::post('transaction/modify/signdoc', 'TransactionsController@signdoc');
 //this is the route to the function in controller

Route::get('transaction/getbc/{transactionID}','TransactionsController@getBC');
Route::get('transaction/showAll', 'TransactionsController@show');
Route::post('transaction/delete', 'TransactionsController@delete');
Route::get('transaction/modify/{id}', 'TransactionsController@modify');
Route::post('transaction/modify/store', 'TransactionsController@update');
Route::post('transaction/modify/addcashflow', 'TransactionsController@addcashflow');
Route::post('transaction/modify/modifycashflow', 'TransactionsController@modifycashflow');
Route::post('transaction/modify/deletecashflow', 'TransactionsController@deletecashflow');
Route::post('transaction/modify/deletedoc', 'TransactionsController@deletedoc');

Route::get('transaction/confirm','TransactionsController@confirmInquiry');
Route::post('transaction/add','TransactionsController@add');
Route::get('/transaction/download/{id}', 'TransactionsController@getDownload');
```

In my transaction controller

```
class TransactionsController extends Controller
{
    public function signdoc(Request $request){
        //TODO
        // save image
        echo "signdoc";
        log::info("sign doc controller asdfsadfsafsadfsad");
return response()->json(['status'=>'success','info'=>' entered sign doc     function!!'])
        ->header('Content-Type','json');

   }
}
```

in the terminal I check the php artisan route:list and the routes seems correct

```
       | web          |
|        | POST      | transaction/add                       |                           | App\Http\Controllers\TransactionsController@add
       | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | transaction/confirm                   |                           | App\Http\Controllers\TransactionsController@confirmInquiry
       | web,auth     |
|        | POST      | transaction/delete                    |                           | App\Http\Controllers\TransactionsController@delete
       | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | transaction/download/{id}             |                           | App\Http\Controllers\TransactionsController@getDownload
       | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | transaction/getbc/{transactionID}     |                           | App\Http\Controllers\TransactionsController@getBC
       | web,auth     |
|        | POST      | transaction/modify/addcashflow        |                           | App\Http\Controllers\TransactionsController@addcashflow
       | web,auth     |
|        | POST      | transaction/modify/deletecashflow     |                           | App\Http\Controllers\TransactionsController@deletecashflow
       | web,auth     |
|        | POST      | transaction/modify/deletedoc          |                           | App\Http\Controllers\TransactionsController@deletedoc
       | web,auth     |
|        | POST      | transaction/modify/modifycashflow     |                           | App\Http\Controllers\TransactionsController@modifycashflow
       | web,auth     |
|        | POST      | transaction/modify/signdoc            |                           | App\Http\Controllers\TransactionsController@signdoc
       | web,auth     |
|        | POST      | transaction/modify/store              |                           | App\Http\Controllers\TransactionsController@update
       | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | transaction/modify/{id}               |                           | App\Http\Controllers\TransactionsController@modify
       | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | transaction/showAll                   |                           | App\Http\Controllers\TransactionsController@show
       | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | transactionDelete/showAll             |                           | App\Http\Controllers\TransactionsDeleteController@show
       | web,auth     |
|        | POST      | updateOwner                           |                           | App\Http\Controllers\HouseOwnersController@updateOwner
       | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | welcome                               |                           | Closure
       | web          |
```

Comment: Try with the absolute url or if your are in a blade file {{ url('/transaction/modify/signdoc') }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use name in the route ... ->name('transaction.modify.sincdoc');

```
Route::post('transaction/modify/signdoc', 'TransactionsController@signdoc')->name('transaction.modify.sincdoc');
```

And the blade where you are writing the url use route clause

```
url:"{{route('transaction.modify.syncdoc')}}",
```

Please try this and let me know how it works :)

Comment: Thank You for the response but it turns out the laravel Controller folder had some back up files with the same name in a .bak folder in Controller folder. Laravel was calling the TransactionsController in the .bak folder and I was modifying TransactionsController in the controller folder.